# Finding nth occurrence of a pattern within a string in SQL (Presto)

Tags: regex, presto, trino

I am writing a query in Presto SQL using the function regexp_extract

I have a string that may look like the following examples:

```
'1A2B2C3D3E'
'1A1B2C2D3E'
'1A2B1C2D2E'
```

What I'm trying to do is find for example the **second** occurrence of 1[A-E].

If I try

```
regexp_extract(col, '(1[A-E])(1[A-E])', 2)
```

This will work for the second example (and the first since it returns nothing since there is no second occurence). However, this will fail for the third example. It returns nothing. I know that is because my regex is searching for a 1[A-E] followed **directly** by another 1[A-E].

So then I tried

```
regexp_extract(col, '(1[A-E])(.*)(1[A-E])', 3)
```

But this does not work either. I am not sure how I can account for the fact that I may have 1A1B2C or 1A2B1C to find that second 1. Any help?

Comment: I don't know about Presto but your second pattern looks like it should work. The only thing is that you should use a lazy quantifier (i.e., `.*?` instead of `.*`) otherwise group 3 will contain the _last_ occurrence, not necessarily the _second_ one. What exactly do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get any results at all?

Answer (score 3):

Your second pattern does work in the latest version of Trino ([formerly known as Presto SQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)):

```
WITH t(col) AS (
  VALUES 
    '1A2B2C3D3E', 
    '1A1B2C2D3E',
    '1A2B1C2D2E')
SELECT regexp_extract(col, '(1[A-E])(.*)(1[A-E])', 3)
FROM t
```

```
 _col0
-------
 NULL
 1B
 1C
(3 rows)
```

As others have commented, you don't need the capture groups for the first match or for the `.*`, and you should use the lazy quantifier to avoid `.*` eagerly matching all characters between the first and last occurrence:

```sql
WITH t(col) AS (
    VALUES 
        '1A2B2C3D3E', 
        '1A1B2C2D3E',
        '1A2B1C2D2E', 
        '1A2B1C2D1E') 
SELECT regexp_extract(col, '1[A-E].*?(1[A-E])', 1)
FROM t
```

```
 _col0
-------
 NULL
 1B
 1C
 1C
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second capture group `(.*)` to keep the 2 capture groups in the result, and you can optionally match the allowed characters in between.

From what I read on [this page](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html) you might also consider using `regexp_extract_all` to get all the matches, as `regexp_extract` returns the first match.

As the example data consists of a digit followed by a char A-E, you could exclude matching the 1 from the character class to prevent overmatching  and backtracking.

```
(1[A-E])[02-9A-E]*(1[A-E])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JMXnNw/1)

If using a single capture group to get the second value is also ok, you can use

```
1[A-E][02-9A-E]*(1[A-E])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F4T6Bk/1)

Comment: What made the OP's original pattern "not work" though?

Comment: @41686d6564 I think using `regexp_extract` instead of `regexp_extract_all`, but I have no experience with presto.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately the program that I am writing this query in doesn't let me use regex_extract_all. Even worse, for some reason your solution is not working in this program (even tho I think it's correct).  In the part with the [0-9A-E]*, is there a way to EXCLUDE 1? so that it only searches for 0, 2-9? Sorry not that great with regex

Comment: @user9592573 _"s there a way to EXCLUDE 1?"_ Isn't that exactly what the second pattern in this very answer does?

Comment: @user9592573 If getting a single group for the second value is also ok, you can use `1[A-E][02-9A-E]*(1[A-E])` https://regex101.com/r/F4T6Bk/1